# How can i add vertical space to a line in a row? need solution

Tags: spacing

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{Lots of vertical rules}  \label{tab:a}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
    \hline
    Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
    & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
    \hline
    &  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MBTI}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FFM}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BFI}}} &\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{KTS}}} & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{BTR}}} &\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NEO-FFI}}} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{L|}{} \\ 
    \hline

    [10] & & & & & & 
    & Interactive personality profiling approach 
    & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
    & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

\end{table}

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\multirow`?

Comment: Yes i am using \multirow

Comment: Because you have blank rows, it is not entirely clear what you want the result to look like...blank rows eliminated?  vertical labels on separate row? etc...

Comment: i want the line after the vertical text in the cell. as it comes over the vertical text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting `\multirow` in a `\parbox` doesn't seem the best approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,ragged2e,graphicx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\rotcell}[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{Lots of vertical rules}  \label{tab:a}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
\hline
Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used} & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
\hline
& \rotcell{MBTI} & \rotcell{FFM} & \rotcell{BFI} & \rotcell{KTS} & \rotcell{BTR} &\rotcell{NEO-FFI} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
\hline

[10] & & & & & &
& Interactive personality profiling approach
& Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
& In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
\hline
& & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @IftikharAhmad Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.

Comment: @samcarter Ok i have clicked on checkmark.

Comment: @samcarter I have an issue regarding this table. I want to continue this table on next page as it ia a long table. please help me in this regard.

Comment: @IftikharAhmad Have a look at the `longtable` package

Comment: it does not works in my document because i have used table and tabularx

Comment: i have posted question regarding that please have a look @samcarter